# Change laravel morpth migration field to nullable

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I want to change morph field that already exists to nullable in laravel.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->nullableMorphs('cartable')->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->morphs('cartable')->change();
    });
}
```

I get error `Call to a member function change() on null`, anyone has idea how to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do it by calling `->change()`. I think you need to use `->dropMorphs()` and then create the column again. You should be weary to check if this retains the existing data and everything functions as supposed to after. 
See the documentation here [Available Command Aliases](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#available-command-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Schema builder doesn't support modifying morphs fields directly. You need to manually change each column that makes up the morphs field.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cartable_id')->nullable()->change();
        $table->string('cartable_type')->nullable()->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cartable_id')->nullable(false)->change();
        $table->string('cartable_type')->nullable(false)->change();
    });
}
```

Note: A morphs field typically consists of two columns: an ID column and a type column.